# Java Encapsulation without getter setter methods

Tags: java, encapsulation

Can we achieve encapsulation in java without having any getter or setter methods?

For example, the code below

```
class A {

  private int id;
  private String name;

}
```

Can we say that above code satisfies encapsulation?

Comment: Well, encapsulation is essentially hiding implementation details that aren't necessary to the user of the class, as well as not exposing unnecessary details. In effect, this is usually seen as keeping all fields as `protected` or stricter. In terms of your posed code, it's not really "encapsulated" because you're not doing anything with it at the moment anyhow. Providing a getter wouldn't break encapsulation, it's a way to provide information without allowing risky access to the fields. You can provide calculated info and return that, but in essence they're still "getters".

Comment: Only existing getter/setter/code can break encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can say that this class satisfies encapsulation. It does not expose internal state or implementation. If you add method that will use these fields it is encapsulation in action. The main idea of encapsulation is to hide internal implementation from the user of the class.

Comment: exactly, getters are meant for exposing only what you want, and setters are for setting without letting the user know how it is set

Answer (score 0):

Partially, Actually there is literally no use of the code that you presented but making all the variables private alone will not make that an encapsulation.

Encapsulation means "binding the data and data members together" means joining data and methods related to that data in a class to form an encapsulated object.

And also to hide the direct usage of data members!.